# Mockito --passing objects to the tested class give null

Tags: mockito

i created a test case where i have to pass ojects to the tested class from the test class
i created the object and populated its variable and it is not null when i check it in the test class
but when its being passed to the actual class the values are not there any more, and it gives a null pointer

ex:
from test class

```
String a="a";
String b="b";
Mo mo =new Mo(a,b)
Bo bo = new Bo(Mo,"anyThing")
if(mo.bo!=null)
{
call the tested class
tested.callMe(bo,"anything")
}
```

NOW IN THE TESTED CLASS 
public callMe(Bo bo,String anything)

```
{
if (bo.getMo().getA()==null)
{
it give true
}
}
```

PS 
i used everything

```
@Mock
Mo mo;
@Mock
Bo bo;
@InjectMocks
Mo mo;
@InjectMocks
Bo bo;
```

created the Mo, Bo in the @Before Method and gave it values
instatiated Mo,Bo in the testCallMe () in  the test class
and it is always the same

when checked in the test class it is ok 
but in the tested class it is null

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from your code snippets what the problem is. Could you provide a minimal example that compiles?

You stated that you're using @InjectMocks. That only supports setter injection. If you're injecting dependencies via constructor, then @InjectMocks isn't going to do anything for you.

Comment: i said i tried using the InjectMocks as well as Mock and also tried constructing the objects and give it fake values to test it .. the problem that i have is the values that i give for Mo is only available when i check for them in the test class .. but once i make the call to the tested method the object is null